# Chaining models while rendering JSON in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

How can I chain multiple models to be rendered as a JSON object in rails. 
Currently I have a render statement like

```
render json: current_user.role.selected_bids.to_json(include: [:project => {include: [:milestones , :skill_category] } ] )
```

I want to append to this JSON object another model where I get to include a model associated to :milestones. Something like this

```
render json: current_user.role.selected_bids.to_json
(include: [:project => {include: [:milestones=> {include: [:timetrackers]}, 
:skill_category]}])
```

but its throwing a syntax error. Is it possible to do this level of nesting or should I make another API call ?

Comment: You could use serialiser to structure the json or a view based solution such as jbuilder.

Comment: Oh okay, but is it not possible to include an association here itself ?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json Check out the last block. "2nd level and higher order associations work as well"

Comment: @Anton thanks alot mate :)

Comment: You welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a syntax error is because you are trying to create a `Hash` using syntax you would use to create an `Array`. You can instead do this something like this:

```
render json: current_user.role.selected_bids.to_json(
  include: [
    project: { 
      include: [  
        {
          milestones: {
            include: [:timetrackers]
          }, 
        },
        :skill_category
      ]
    }
  ]
)
```

Comment: Notice how I have wrapped the `milestones` key inside curly braces to indicate its a `Hash`.